# T(n) = T(n-1) + 10/n

Tags: divide-and-conquer, recurrence

What I have done so far is:

```
T(n-1) + 10/n

T((n-1)-1) + 10/(n-1) + 10/n =             T(n-2) + 10/(n+1) + 10/n

T((n-2)-1) + 10/(n+2) + 10/(n+1) + 10/n =  T(n-3) + 10/(n+2) + 10/(n+1) + 10/n
```

Assume   `n-k = 1,`

So... I get lost here,

```
T(n-k) + ??
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about mathematics and not programming.

Answer (score 2):

well what i understand is:

> T(n)  =T(n-1) + 10/n
>
> T(n-1)=T(n-2) + 10/(n-1)
>
> T(n-2)=T(n-3) + 10/(n-2)
>
> T(n)  =T(n-2) + 10/(n-1) + 10/n
>
> T(n)  =T(n-3) + 10/(n-2) + 10/(n-1) + 10/n

similarly,

> T(n)  =T(n-k) + 10/(n-k) + 10/(n-k+1) + 10/(n-k+2)+......... + 10/n

for n-k=1:

> T(n)  =T(1)   +10*(1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ................1/n )

so,
(1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ................1/n ) is a harmonic progression its sum cant be found perfectly but its proportional to log(n).

**so, T(n) is of order of log(n).**

[sum of harmonic progression:click here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2234/sum-of-harmonic-progression)

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the boundary condition `T(1)=1`, otherwise the recurrence is not well defined.

You can write the recurrence out:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + 10/n = T(n-2) + 10/(n-1) + 10/n
     = ...
     = 10 * (1/n + 1/(n-1) + ... + 1)
     = 10 * H_n,
```

where `H_n` is the n-th [Harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). It is very well-known that `H_n=Theta(log n)`. (You can prove this by noting that `log n = integral from 1 to n 1/n dn` and that the sum `1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/n` is bounded from above by that integral.)

Hence `T(n) = Theta(log n)`.